# My 30A PDU is drawing 20.5A. It's L6-30P plug gets hot (65°C. Ambient: 35°C). Is this safe?

Tags: power-supply, power

I have a home server setup that is drawing 20.5A from a dedicated 30A line. The power is supplied via a PDU rated for 30A (240V). The PDU's plug runs a bit hot, and I'm nervous if it would be safe to use this setup.

Here're some facts:

- The PDU has L6-30P plug. It's temp is stable at 65°C.
- The server room's ambient temperature is about 35°C.
- The supply wire (10 AWG) or the rest of the PDU's cord isn't that hot (about 40°C).

Is it a good idea to keep this setup? Or should I split the load to another PDU on a separate line?

Comment: PDU = power distribution unit?

Comment: Assuming it's running on 120 V, 2400 W is quite a lot for a "home" server. Is it some hobby equipment that would normally live in a data centre? Is the plug moulded on, or can you open it to check that the wire connections are secure?

Comment: Is the plug pins clean? Shut it down, unplug it, and rub steel wool or scotchbrite on the plug pins until they are smooth and shine. Clean, reinstall, startup, re-measure temp. Contact resistance is important for high-current connections.

Comment: The spec sheets for L30 plugs I've seen have listed a maximum temperature rise of 30C but I assume that's at 30A; you should be seeing less than half of that at 20.5A.  As @rdtsc says, cleaning would remove some contact corrosion but the way the plug mates, most of it should be getting wiped off.  If the plug is some super cheap no-name brand, I would suggest getting one from a reputable supplier.  Ditto the receptacle.

Comment: Is it mostly the plug that gets hot or also the receptacle on the wall?  Sometimes a worn out receptacle with poor contact pressure can heat up quite a bit.  If you're using components rated for 30A continuous, it's definitely suspicious for things to be that hot at 20A.

Comment: @Transistor: Bingo

Comment: @AndrewMorton: It's on 240v. Yeah it's a new territory for me and I'm a bit scared TBH. I have full access to the space.

Comment: @rdtsc: I definitely should double check this. Thank you!!

Comment: @vir: I agree -- it's higher than I expected so I feel something is fishy.

Comment: @KH: I'd say it's mostly the plug, but I can't say for sure because the receptacle isn't directly exposed. The receptacle is brand new out of the box. The PDU (and its plug) is a retired commercial server equipment so it's seen some action. I should check its blades.

Comment: Well just FYI a 30A circuit is often rated at 80% continuous duty (you can look up the breaker that feeds it to find out.  If it's particularly long, the wires should have been derated and oversized, but you can't really do much about that now without spending a lot of money.  One option is to embiggen the 10 guage cable feeding the unit and/or put a new plug on it and another is to hire an electrician to hardwire it.  If you want to get fancy you can use a junction box with isolated terminal lugs.